# oracle refresh mview before select statement

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

in my application I need to refresh materialized view before select from it (in one sql statement)

I've tried following:

```
begin 
dbms_mview.refresh('MYMV');
end;

select * from MYMV
```

Following errors occured:
ORA-06550, PLS-00103

Comment: This cannot be done in one SQL statement, because the refresh is only possible from PL/SQL. Would be interesting to know why you need it.

Comment: I just need fresh data in select.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a single SQL statement?

Comment: External software restriction